# Show line number and file name using angular2-logger

Tags: angular

I'm using [Angular2-logger](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger) inside my project.

```
import { Logger } from "angular2-logger/core";
...
logger: Logger;
...
logger.info('<log string>')
```

Output printed in console like image below

[image]

Is there any option in *Angular2-logger* or alternative class that I can use to show **file name** and **line number** of where I'm calling ***logger*** methods ?  (same as `console.log(...)` like image bellow)

[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: did you tried using the different levels of logging like info, log, debug, etc.? Does it not give you required information?

Comment: Yes I've tried but I they wouldn't  help.

Comment: Why not use console.log(...)?

Comment: Cause if you use angular2-logger you can switch it off and on so easily with changing just one line. in large projects you cant use console.log() @junior-gantin

Comment: @ValaKhosravi check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution by this way:

1- I created a `LoggerService`.

2- I imported the service to `app.module.ts` and use it as a provider.

3- `LoggerService` looks like something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
    public error(message) {
        try { throw new Error(); } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.stack);
            const stackTraces = e.stack.split('at');
            const fileList = stackTraces[2].substr(
                stackTraces[2].lastIndexOf('/src'),
                stackTraces[2].length - 1 ).replace(')', ''
            );
            const functionName = stackTraces[2].substr(0, stackTraces[2].indexOf('(') - 1);

            // Do whatever you want, use console.log or angular2-logger service
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you **`not`** to **`use`** any **`logger libraries`** for two reasons

- when angular provides it by default.
- These libraries are not dependable with the version updates.

As we log the errors on the front end (i.e browser environment), You could make a  custom logger service.

Regarding the issue you mentioned, you can switch off the logs by overwriting the service via **`usevalue`** with an empty class/function depending on environment  that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Logger's `info` method which is least verbose. There is no way to configure it in such way as you'd want to. The alternative is to use `error` and `warning` methods - they provide stack trace with filename and line number.

[image: Logs in console from Angular2-logger methods]

Comment: Sorry but I can't change all `info`s to `warring` or `error`